# New disks not recognized on Solaris 10 update 11

Tags: resize, solaris

We are installing Solaris 10 update 11 (x86-64) and have a small problem.
new disks added (or disks resized) are not being recognized by the system automatically.

We have to reboot and configure them manually.

While on Solaris 10 update 9 & update 10, it was working fine.
as long as we added a new disk, we could immediately see it in "format" (or after a small "devfsadm -c disks").

On the update 11, nothing.

I have tried all things like :

- cfgadm -al
- devfsadm
- devfsadm -c disks
- drvconfig
- disks
- svcadm enable hotplug
- etc..

Still can't see any disks added.
(nb : it's virtual machines on vmware)
and it was working fine with builds 9 & 10.

Any heard of that bug ?
Also, what else can I try to force a re scan of disks ? except a reboot.

Comment: More details would help.  What kind of disks?  (iSCSI, etc)

Comment: hi, regular SCSI disks.

Comment: Which VMWare SCSI controller are you using for your VMs?  Do the disks appear under `raidctl` or, if you have it and are using an LSI controller, `lsiutil`?

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer.

Comment: hi, can't see them in raidctl unfortunately (only the first 3 disks, i can't see the additional one). also, controler is LSI Logic Parallel. i can try to add a new controler (different one) with new disks. but the LSI should work (i don't have lsiutil, gonna try to download it).

Comment: I'd also recommend that you open a trouble ticket with Oracle if you have a support contract.

Comment: its apparently a bug with LSI Logic Parallel SCSI Controller. LSI Logic SAS works fine. i'll create a ticket @ Oracle to see if they have a patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my old question.

It was back in the days a bug with the "**LSI Logic Parallel**" SCSI Controller (not compliant with build 11). "**LSI Logic SAS**" worked fine.

Its worth mentionning that it was on an old **VMware ESX 6.0** and we just had to change the controller type to make it work.